# install xgboost on anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, xgboost

I installed xgboost following this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_on_Mac_OSX?lang=en). It works fine with my python3.  My question is what do I need to do to have it work on my anaconda? I tried to import xgboost on my anaconda but failed. Could anyone help me with that? Thank you so much!

Comment: The libraries installed to system wide python should be accessible everywhere. Are you using virtualenv? How did you install xgboost? What is the install path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install it through the conda-forge channel by running this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost=0.6a2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can follow these steps :
 1. In anaconda Prompt type the command  "anaconda search -t conda xgboost"
   it will show the bunch of list of packages according to the OS 
 2. select the appropriate name of the "xgboost" package 
 3. and type the command "conda install -c mikesilva xgboost"
 note:- my os is win 64 ans python 3.6 so I choose **mikesilve**